# Why ruby and python math calculation are different

Tags: python, ruby, math

```
2 + 2 / - 7 * - 7 * 8 - 5 + 7 * -3
```

Python calculates this expression like this:

```
2+2/-7*-7*8-5+7*-3 == -8.0
# True
```

And Ruby like this:

```
2+2/-7*-7*8-5+7*-3 == 32
# => true
```

But the correct answer is `-8`.

Where am I wrong? Why the Ruby result is different from the Python one?

Comment: Python 2.x will give you 32, and Python 3.x will give you -8. The difference is whether `/` does integer division or not. (Python 3.x changed this.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Python

```py
>>> 2+2/-7*-7*8-5+7*-3 == -8.0
True
```

because `/` does floating point division.

But in Ruby `/` means integer division.

To make Python work like Ruby you need to use `//`.

Breaking it down:

In Python:

```py
2+2/-7*-7*8-5+7*-3
  = 2 + 2 / (-7) * (-7) * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 2 / (-7) * (-7) * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + (-0.2857142857142857) * (-7) * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 2.0 * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 16.0 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 16.0 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 16.0 - 5 + (-21)
  = -8.0
```

In Ruby,

```rb
2+2/-7*-7*8-5+7*-3
  = 2 + 2 / (-7) * (-7) * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + (-1) * (-7) * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 7 * 8 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 2 + 56 - 5 + 7 * (-3)
  = 58 - 5 + (7 * -3)
  = 53 + (7 * -3)
  = 53 + (-21)
  = 32
```

Basically in Ruby (and old Python, i.e., Python 2):

```rb
2 / (-7)   ==  -1
```

while in Python (i.e., Python 3, which has been around SINCE ***2008***):

```py
2 / (-7)   ==  -0.2857142857142857
2 // (-7)  ==  -1
```

As pointed out, correctly so, in the comments, there is an old version of Python called Python 2 (that people still use today!) for which `/` works like it does in Ruby.

While many people are waiting for Python 2 to die, it is hanging on (and still doing well), and so, yes, it is best to qualify Python 2 vs. Python 3. It is clear from the question that the O.P. is using the unqualified term "Python" to apply to Python 3, which in a perfect world, would be what we can all say. After all, does anyone use Python "1"? :-)

Comment: The behaviour of / changed from Python 2 to Python 3, so your answer is not universally correct.

Comment: You are correct. As much as I try to pretend Python 2 does not exist, it actually does, and truth and reality should take precedence over my dreams. :)

Comment: "Most people are waiting for Python 2 to die". Is there any recent source for this claim? Last time I looked, there were still more users of Python2 than Python3.

Comment: Hyperbole. But your point is well taken; I will change it to say "many".

Answer (score 12):

This example is simpler:

In Ruby (and Python 2.x), `1/2 == 0`. In Python 3.x, it's `0.5`.

What's happening is that in Ruby and Python 2, `/` between two integers performs integer division (floors the true result).

The below will give you `-8` in Ruby. Note the `2.0`, making that a floating point value:

```
2+2.0/-7*-7*8-5+7*-3
```

Comment: I know it floors in Python, rather than truncating. I'm not familiar with Ruby, but Ruby seems to be flooring as well - that, or something else I'm not aware of is confounding my experiments. (I couldn't find any relevant Ruby docs.)

Comment: @user2357112: You're right, the corresponding [doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-2F) is useless. Ruby integer division uses flooring, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your first question.

Assuming that your Python and Ruby reports are correct, obviously, there is only one place left as the answer to your question: "Where am I wrong?". That is,

> But the correct answer is -8.

As you have confirmed yourself, the correct answer for your Python environment is `-8.0`, and for your Ruby environment, it is `32`.